# android dialog won't load full data

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I have dialogs open based on `imageButtons` i can open my dialogs for each `imageButton` but my dialogs won't show full data.

## Issue

1. Buttons in dialog won't show
2. My dialog doesn't have background

## Code

`Custom dialog`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_imageview"
        android:layout_width="294dp"
        android:layout_height="246dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="68dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="274dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="69dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="270dp"
        android:contentDescription="image"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[0]" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="59dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="474dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="59dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="136dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/close_btn"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="285dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="680dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="59dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="193dp"
        android:background="#F50057"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Close"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/play_btn"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="59dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="680dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="289dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="190dp"
        android:background="#00E676"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Play"
        android:textAlignment="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

`Activity function`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_buildings)

        // open dialog1
        val imageButton1 = this.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1) as ImageButton;
        imageButton1.setOnClickListener() {
            val dialog = Dialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar)
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
            dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
            dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_custom)

            val tv_text = dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_text)as TextView
            val btn_close = dialog.findViewById(R.id.close_btn) as Button
            val btn_play = dialog.findViewById(R.id.play_btn) as Button
            val imageView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_imageview) as ImageView

            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.school) //set image here
            tv_text.setText("School")  // set description here


            //insert your button function here
            btn_close.setOnClickListener {
                fun onClick(v: View) {
                    dialog.dismiss()
                }
            }

            btn_play.setOnClickListener {
                fun onClick(v: View) {
                    val mp: MediaPlayer? = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a)
                    mp?.start();
                }
            }

            dialog.show();
        }
}
```

## Screenshot

[image: one]

**Any idea?**

Comment: By *but my dialogs won't show full data.* do you mean won't show the full layout?

Comment: @TamirAbutbul if you see my `xml` code there is `2 buttons` and if you compare it to `screenshot` there is no button in my dialog. that's what i mean.

Comment: Ok i will work on answer soon and let you know when i am done

Comment: @TamirAbutbul thank you

Comment: I have posted my answer, feel free to check it and comment me if anything is not clear.

Comment: Ok here is screen shot of what I get on your answer and also what I'm looking for   https://ibb.co/WgPzdWP

Comment: Try to change `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to `wrap_content` and also make the view dimentiones smaller (change this attribute `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"`). If this wont help you feel free to contact me via my [linkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/in/tamir-abutbul-10a695178/) for more help

Comment: thanks man, still didn't solve the issue. and I'm not sure what is difference to chat here rather than LinkedIn, anyway, thanks for the help but I'll prefer wait here to get answers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200411/discussion-between-tamir-abutbul-and-mafortis).

Answer (score 0):

**Different phones got different screen size**, in your layout you are using fixed size on your view (fixed size is `android:layout_marginTop="474dp"` for example) and the result is that what may look good on one screen (your android studio preview screen) will not look good on another screen (your actual phone).

How can you fix it - you can use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) to make your screen responsive to all screen sizes.

**Take this layout for example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[6]" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Your text here"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.7" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**It will look like this and will be responsive to all screen sizes:**

[image]

---

**This will look like you want it to look but let`s explain what I did:**

- I have used `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"` on the buttons to tell them to be equal in height to `10%` of the screen size (not fixed size dimensions).
- On the same concept, I have also used `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.4"` so the image will be equal to `40%` of the screen size in height.
- I have also used [Guidelines](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html) to better control the position of my buttons.

You can find more information about creating responsive layouts in [Support different screen sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes), [Barriers](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/barriers.html) and as mentioned above [Guidelines](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html) as well

With the above tools, you can create a responsive layout.
You don't have to use `ConstraintLayout` to achieve this, you have other options but I find it the most easy way to creat your layouts.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer but this code not only didn't fixed my issue in fact crashed my dialog, now when i try to open dialog several white screen will loads and return to MainActivity.

Comment: Do you have any log errors that you can share? maybe you were using android.x and not the support library as in my example

Comment: yes i am using `android.x`  error `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com....`

Comment: Just replace `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` with the android x version

Comment: `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout` for constraintLayout and `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline` for the guideline

Comment: i will try it and let you know